# Click Function Not Working in IE - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with my jquery code, I have created a type of calendar where an overlay is presented with additional information if you click on a date. It works fine in chrome, it does exactly what I want but in IE nothing happens when you click on the dates, no overlay is presented. Been struggling with it for a while and really need some help with it. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(let i=0; i<50; i++) {
        $("#calendar" + i).each (function() {
            $(this).click (function() {
                $("#calendar" + i).toggleClass("bigcalendar");      
            }); 
        });
    }
});
```

Here is a link to a working example:

http://codepen.io/kmars/pen/BLbQoA

Comment: which ie version?

Comment: What is purpose of `for` loop?

Comment: Rather, what is the function of the `each`

Comment: Not too familiar with attribute selectors, in fact only just discovered them as Sudharsan S showed me in the solution. Will look into them some more I think, do you guys use them a lot? Sorry for soundin N00b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attribute selector in jquery. No for loop need for clicking dynamic elements in jquery. And the below code should be working in all Browsers.

```
$(document).on('click','[id^=calendar]', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("bigcalendar");  
});
```

Comment: I partly agree on the for loop part.. yet all [#calendar] could be contained in a [div#calendars].